# Обрезка svg-изображения

Tags: html, css, svg

Имеется svg-изображение, в котором от границы общего изображения до собственно начала картинки имеется белый фон, который окружает изображение со всех сторон и создает отступы, что мешает при верстке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно обрезать svg до нужного размера? какой кусок кода отвечает за подложку изображения?

иллюстратора нет, обрезка руками не подойдет, есть только код.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512.001 512.001" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512.001 512.001;" xml:space="preserve" width="388px" height="254px">
<path style="fill:#41479B;" d="M503.172,423.725H8.828c-4.875,0-8.828-3.953-8.828-8.828V97.104c0-4.875,3.953-8.828,8.828-8.828
 h494.345c4.875,0,8.828,3.953,8.828,8.828v317.793C512,419.772,508.047,423.725,503.172,423.725z"/>
<path style="fill:#F5F5F5;" d="M512,97.104c0-4.875-3.953-8.828-8.828-8.828h-39.495l-163.54,107.147V88.276h-88.276v107.147
 L48.322,88.276H8.828C3.953,88.276,0,92.229,0,97.104v22.831l140.309,91.927H0v88.276h140.309L0,392.066v22.831
 c0,4.875,3.953,8.828,8.828,8.828h39.495l163.54-107.147v107.147h88.276V316.578l163.54,107.147h39.495
 c4.875,0,8.828-3.953,8.828-8.828v-22.831l-140.309-91.927H512v-88.276H371.691L512,119.935V97.104z"/>
<g>
 <polygon style="fill:#FF4B55;" points="512,229.518 282.483,229.518 282.483,88.276 229.517,88.276 229.517,229.518 0,229.518 
  0,282.483 229.517,282.483 229.517,423.725 282.483,423.725 282.483,282.483 512,282.483  "/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M178.948,300.138L0.25,416.135c0.625,4.263,4.14,7.59,8.577,7.59h12.159l190.39-123.586H178.948z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M346.388,300.138H313.96l190.113,123.404c4.431-0.472,7.928-4.09,7.928-8.646v-7.258
  L346.388,300.138z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M0,106.849l161.779,105.014h32.428L5.143,89.137C2.123,90.54,0,93.555,0,97.104V106.849z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M332.566,211.863L511.693,95.586c-0.744-4.122-4.184-7.309-8.521-7.309h-12.647L300.138,211.863
  H332.566z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Решение найдено - правка координат в атрибуте viewBox**

Comment: ну вы или нет делали в adobe ilustrator это , там и обрежьте

Comment: @Geyan софтверный способ это, конечно, хорошо. только у меня иллюстратора нет, есть только код, который отрисовывает флаг

Comment: все слои `<g></g>` в коде лишние

Comment: спасибо, убрал пустые слои

Comment: Я не верю что в интернете нет готового флага Великобритании в SVG в нормальном виде

Comment: @AlexeyTen тут дело не в флаге, а возможности управления svg. помимо этого флага пак-изображений, который у меня на руках, включает в себя кучу других svg c аналогичной проблемой. или вы предлагаете на каждую неудобную картинку найти подходящий вариант в сети?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В исходном изображении в первую очередь нас смущает отступ снизу и сверху, которые суммируются с реальным размером изображения и искажают высоту. Ширина изображения равна 100% и зависит только от контейнера.

Следовательно, нужно отрегулировать положение картинки по высоте, ширина растянется сама.

У  элемента имеется атрибут

```
viewBox="min-x, min-y, width, height"
```

который управляет контейнером svg (указывает начальное положение координат и размер элемента-контейнера).

В нашем случае для того, чтобы убрать пустоту сверху - меняем значение min-y, пустоту снизу - уменьшаем высоту контейнера координатой height. Результат такой - viewBox="0 88 512.001 335":

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 88 512.001 335" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512.001 512.001;" xml:space="preserve" width="388px" height="254px">
<path style="fill:#41479B;" d="M503.172,423.725H8.828c-4.875,0-8.828-3.953-8.828-8.828V97.104c0-4.875,3.953-8.828,8.828-8.828
 h494.345c4.875,0,8.828,3.953,8.828,8.828v317.793C512,419.772,508.047,423.725,503.172,423.725z"/>
<path style="fill:#F5F5F5;" d="M512,97.104c0-4.875-3.953-8.828-8.828-8.828h-39.495l-163.54,107.147V88.276h-88.276v107.147
 L48.322,88.276H8.828C3.953,88.276,0,92.229,0,97.104v22.831l140.309,91.927H0v88.276h140.309L0,392.066v22.831
 c0,4.875,3.953,8.828,8.828,8.828h39.495l163.54-107.147v107.147h88.276V316.578l163.54,107.147h39.495
 c4.875,0,8.828-3.953,8.828-8.828v-22.831l-140.309-91.927H512v-88.276H371.691L512,119.935V97.104z"/>
<g>
 <polygon style="fill:#FF4B55;" points="512,229.518 282.483,229.518 282.483,88.276 229.517,88.276 229.517,229.518 0,229.518 
  0,282.483 229.517,282.483 229.517,423.725 282.483,423.725 282.483,282.483 512,282.483  "/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M178.948,300.138L0.25,416.135c0.625,4.263,4.14,7.59,8.577,7.59h12.159l190.39-123.586H178.948z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M346.388,300.138H313.96l190.113,123.404c4.431-0.472,7.928-4.09,7.928-8.646v-7.258
  L346.388,300.138z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M0,106.849l161.779,105.014h32.428L5.143,89.137C2.123,90.54,0,93.555,0,97.104V106.849z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M332.566,211.863L511.693,95.586c-0.744-4.122-4.184-7.309-8.521-7.309h-12.647L300.138,211.863
  H332.566z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Если кто-то укажет недостатки способа, буду рад

Comment: это не решение , просто поверьте

Comment: @Geyan почему?  высота соответствует целевой картинке, ширина автоматически подстраивается под блок, пропорции изображения сохраняются на любом масштабе. "поверьте" или "проверьте"?

Comment: раз так вам плюс репутацию за решение

Answer (score 3):

Ну вообще , если 'мы' не можем редактировать svg то можем взять svg и обернуть в `div` с нужными стилями и `overflow:hidden;` и получим полностью управляемый svg - **смотрим код**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.svg-art {
  width: 510px;
  height: 336px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
#Layer_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -88px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-art">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" width="510px" height="440px">

    <path style="fill:#414798;" d="M503.172,423.725H8.828c-4.875,0-8.828-3.953-8.828-8.828V97.104c0-4.875,3.953-8.828,8.828-8.828
 h494.345c4.875,0,8.828,3.953,8.828,8.828v317.793C512,419.772,508.047,423.725,503.172,423.725z" />
    <path style="fill:#F5F5F5;" d="M512,97.104c0-4.875-3.953-8.828-8.828-8.828h-39.495l-163.54,107.147V88.276h-88.276v107.147
 L48.322,88.276H8.828C3.953,88.276,0,92.229,0,97.104v22.831l140.309,91.927H0v88.276h140.309L0,392.066v22.831
 c0,4.875,3.953,8.828,8.828,8.828h39.495l163.54-107.147v107.147h88.276V316.578l163.54,107.147h39.495
 c4.875,0,8.828-3.953,8.828-8.828v-22.831l-140.309-91.927H512v-88.276H371.691L512,119.935V97.104" />

    <polygon style="fill:#FF4B55;" points="512,229.518 282.483,229.518 282.483,88.276 229.517,88.276 229.517,229.518 0,229.518 
  0,282.483 229.517,282.483 229.517,423.725 282.483,423.725 282.483,282.483 512,282.483  " />
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M178.948,300.138L0.25,416.135c0.625,4.263,4.14,7.59,8.577,7.59h12.159l190.39-123.586H178.948z" />
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M346.388,300.138H313.96l190.113,123.404c4.431-0.472,7.928-4.09,7.928-8.646v-7.258
  L346.388,300.138z" />

    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M0,106.849l161.779,105.014h32.428L5.143,89.137C2.123,90.54,0,93.555,0,97.104V106.849z" />
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M332.566,211.863L511.693,95.586c-0.744-4.122-4.184-7.309-8.521-7.309h-12.647L300.138,211.863
  H332.566z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

в [песочнице](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/ZpwZkg?editors=110) пример адаптивного svg

Comment: нет, не подходит. в вашем способе мы зависим от размеров изображения и подгоняем отступы. обрезка нужна чтобы как раз избавить от белых полей, а не скрыть их - они мешают при верстке

Comment: это тоже самое , ваше дело , все лишние поля убрал за счёт блока - а остальное дело техники - как обычная  вёрстка

Comment: @while1pass svg по сути тоже изображение ,и вести себя с ним надо как с ` img`

Comment: да, я понял, ваш способ можно использовать, но хотелось бы узнать, можно ли поправить код для получения результата. прелесть svg как раз в правке простым текстовым редактором

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko иллюстратора нет

Comment: @while1pass там есть path - это координаты на осях , как видите статичные - переправлять наверно ни кто не будет , а может я ошибаюсь

Comment: @while1pass, "прелесть svg как раз в правке простым текстовым редактором " ну да если это цвет заливка или если это простая фигура. Нужно пересчитывать начало координат (и соответственно все другие координаты). Как по мне прелесть как раз в том, что можно что угодно нарисовать в графическом редакторе, а потом это все вставить в код.)

Comment: @Geyan решил, двух цифр хватило, к стилям можно не притргиваться

Answer (score 1):

Нормально проходит обрезка руками. В IDEA можно такие штуки делать.

Поля чуть-чуть остались, но это для квадратности.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" height="512">
    <path style="fill:#41479B;" d="M503.172,423.725H8.828c-4.875,0-8.828-3.953-8.828-8.828V97.104c0-4.875,3.953-8.828,8.828-8.828 h494.345c4.875,0,8.828,3.953,8.828,8.828v317.793C512,419.772,508.047,423.725,503.172,423.725z"/>
    <path style="fill:#F5F5F5;" d="M512,97.104c0-4.875-3.953-8.828-8.828-8.828h-39.495l-163.54,107.147V88.276h-88.276v107.147 L48.322,88.276H8.828C3.953,88.276,0,92.229,0,97.104v22.831l140.309,91.927H0v88.276h140.309L0,392.066v22.831 c0,4.875,3.953,8.828,8.828,8.828h39.495l163.54-107.147v107.147h88.276V316.578l163.54,107.147h39.495 c4.875,0,8.828-3.953,8.828-8.828v-22.831l-140.309-91.927H512v-88.276H371.691L512,119.935V97.104z"/>
    <polygon style="fill:#FF4B55;" points="512,229.518 282.483,229.518 282.483,88.276 229.517,88.276 229.517,229.518 0,229.518 0,282.483 229.517,282.483 229.517,423.725 282.483,423.725 282.483,282.483 512,282.483"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M178.948,300.138L0.25,416.135c0.625,4.263,4.14,7.59,8.577,7.59h12.159l190.39-123.586H178.948z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M346.388,300.138H313.96l190.113,123.404c4.431-0.472,7.928-4.09,7.928-8.646v-7.258 L346.388,300.138z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M0,106.849l161.779,105.014h32.428L5.143,89.137C2.123,90.54,0,93.555,0,97.104V106.849z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M332.566,211.863L511.693,95.586c-0.744-4.122-4.184-7.309-8.521-7.309h-12.647L300.138,211.863 H332.566z"/>
</svg>
```

Если квадратность не нужна, тогда можно так:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 88 512 336" width="512" height="336">
    <path style="fill:#41479B;" d="M503.172,423.725H8.828c-4.875,0-8.828-3.953-8.828-8.828V97.104c0-4.875,3.953-8.828,8.828-8.828 h494.345c4.875,0,8.828,3.953,8.828,8.828v317.793C512,419.772,508.047,423.725,503.172,423.725z"/>
    <path style="fill:#F5F5F5;" d="M512,97.104c0-4.875-3.953-8.828-8.828-8.828h-39.495l-163.54,107.147V88.276h-88.276v107.147 L48.322,88.276H8.828C3.953,88.276,0,92.229,0,97.104v22.831l140.309,91.927H0v88.276h140.309L0,392.066v22.831 c0,4.875,3.953,8.828,8.828,8.828h39.495l163.54-107.147v107.147h88.276V316.578l163.54,107.147h39.495 c4.875,0,8.828-3.953,8.828-8.828v-22.831l-140.309-91.927H512v-88.276H371.691L512,119.935V97.104z"/>
    <polygon style="fill:#FF4B55;" points="512,229.518 282.483,229.518 282.483,88.276 229.517,88.276 229.517,229.518 0,229.518 0,282.483 229.517,282.483 229.517,423.725 282.483,423.725 282.483,282.483 512,282.483"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M178.948,300.138L0.25,416.135c0.625,4.263,4.14,7.59,8.577,7.59h12.159l190.39-123.586H178.948z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M346.388,300.138H313.96l190.113,123.404c4.431-0.472,7.928-4.09,7.928-8.646v-7.258 L346.388,300.138z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M0,106.849l161.779,105.014h32.428L5.143,89.137C2.123,90.54,0,93.555,0,97.104V106.849z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M332.566,211.863L511.693,95.586c-0.744-4.122-4.184-7.309-8.521-7.309h-12.647L300.138,211.863 H332.566z"/>
</svg>
```